# C# List querying and grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this list:

```
OrderId    ProductId    DateTime

1               1                10.01.2012
1               2                09.01.2012
2               1                11.01.2012
3               1                12.01.2012
3               2                13.01.2012
```

I want to extract another another List from this that's only `ProductId==1` and DateTime is `10.01.2012`.

i.e. only `productId==1` for every OrderId's.

Also I only want the least dateTime version of that item.

So for the above list, 10.01.2012 is the least dateTime where the productId==1.

Result Table;

```
OrderId    ProductId    DateTime

1               1                10.01.2012
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this `list1.Where(id => id.ProductId == 1).OrderBy(p => p.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: but I can only take productId ==1 record. if productId isnt same orderId's.I want to take if productId same my AllOrderId's. this meaning. orderId==1 contain productId==1,orderId==2 contain productId==1,orderId==3 contain productId==1. do u understand me?

Comment: I want to productId ==1 but if this productId used every orderId. 
orderId ==1,orderıd==2,orderıd ==3.

Comment: How many such `OrderId` exist ? {1,2,3, ...} all those should have a particular product and you need to pick up the one with the min date ? Please edit the question with further details as what is exactly to be done with the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
myList = myList.Where(x.ProductId == 1).OrderBy(x => x.DateTime);
```

That will order your new list by the DateTime value where the productId is equal to 1. If you want to get only the first one, you can use the .First() method of the list, e.g:

```
myCustomType = myList.Where(x => x.ProductId == 1).OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).First();
```

Comment: ProductId==1 is true but this will be dynamic. cause I dont know which productId is same every OrderId's. so I have only list and list look like to i show to you. now; how can I know, which productId is same every orderId's in myList?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you trying to find duplicate products in an order?

Comment: no.first of all i want to find dublicated products in a order. but I dont know how can I do this?